# Tearing in HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, tearing

I'm making a small game using the HTML5 `canvas` element.  It works great, except that it has a scrolling background with obvious tearing happening in Firefox and Chromium browsers in Ubuntu.  I'm pretty sure it's buffered because there isn't any of the flickering I'd expect; just tearing.  Is there any way to work around this or time rendering to right after the last screen refresh?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025661/how-can-i-get-vsync-callback-on-html5-canvas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no way to control the actual repainting of a canvas element(which if there was, could actually help in increasing performance I guess). So one can only hope that the browser actually does something intelligent, rather than screwing up like in your case.

I myself have quite some experience with the canvas element and know of its quirks. I ran into some kind of "repaint lag" several times by now, where obviously the actual numbers behind the scenes are correct and "smooth", but the graphics still have a somewhat "jumpy" behavior, which in fact is *really* annoying.

Only thing I can imagine that could have an effect in your case, is activating VSync in the driver settings of your Graphics Card.

If you'd like to provide a link to your game that might be helpful too, since I'm also running Ubuntu here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, I'm currently using placeholder art stolen from another game, so I cannot distribute it until the art is all replaced.  I'm also seeing the lag issue you mentioned.