# Canvas Arc or QuadCurve OnMouseOver function possible?

Tags: html, canvas, css

I have a round diagram for which I need to display a div when users hover over each section (arcs).

I was going to use canvas: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-planets-image-map/
But I have not been able to draw an arc in canvas - or should I use any other technology to create this?

Comment: The example URL you include even _shows_ how to create an arc (although it is using it to draw a full circle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [draw an arc in HTML5 Canvas](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-arcs/), using either the [`arc()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-2dcontext-20100304/#dom-context-2d-arc) or [`arcTo()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-2dcontext-20100304/#dom-context-2d-arcto) methods of the context.

You can see an example of arcs drawn in HTML5 Canvas in this little game I wrote:
http://phrogz.net/tmp/connections.html
*The game concept is not mine, just the implementation.*

Note that with a squared-off line cap style, you can even draw wedges (circle segments) with a single `arc` command.

Comment: Thanks for the help - I run into 2 issues when doing arcs:

1- my onhover effects do not work unless arc is filled (which I know I am probably not doing it right but I am not sure how else to do it) and 

2. the arcs cannot be filled since it's a round diagram with one arc inside another

Comment: I guess all I need is a context.onMouseover (if exists?) that works in the arc border/line. Let me know if you know how please :)

Comment: You need to read [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596434/clear-canvas-rect-but-keep-background/5600671#5600671), the section titled _"Basics: HTML5 Canvas as a Non-Retained Drawing Mode Graphics API"_. The canvas cannot detect you hovering over a particular region. I strongly suggest that you consider using SVG instead of HTML5 Canvas.