# HTML5 canvas: Can I draw a shape and give it a variable name?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I would like to draw a shape on the canvas (which I can do) but I'm not sure if it's possible to give that shape a variable name. I want to do this so I can then change the width of that shape later without having to redraw the shape.

Can somebody help? Thanks.

Comment: You could take a look at KineticJS <http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-rect-tutorial/> for some advanced canvas manipulation.

Comment: You clearly do not understand how the HTML5 canvas works. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/a/5600671/405017

Comment: Using an abstraction library like [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com) could help.

Comment: If you want to manipulate drawing objects [use SVG](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-map-element.html#svg-0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do that unfortunately without redrawing the shape. What you could do is store the information in an object like so.

```
var rectangle = {x:10,y:20,width:20,height:40};
```

Then you can change any of the values and redraw it like so,

```
//clear the canvas then draw
rectangle.width = 60;
ctx.fillRect(rectangle.x,rectangle.y,rectangle.width,rectangle.height);
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/QrCuj/)**