# clearRect produces white box (not removes set colors)

Tags: javascript

I have multiple stacked contexts in a canvas (each will be displaying circles, then deleting cirles, creating new circle in new location on the context). I was testing the feasibility with this code:

```
var radius = 10;
cx2 = document.getElementById("myCanvasID").getContext('2d');
cx2.beginPath();
cx2.arc(150, 150, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
cx2.closePath();
cx2.fillStyle = '#6495ED';
cx2.fill();
cx2.lineWidth = 2;
cx2.strokeStyle = '#003300';
cx2.stroke();

//ctx2.fillColor = "rgba(0-255, 0-255, 0-255, 0-1)"   
cx2.clearRect(0,0,300,300);
//cx2.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out"
//cx2.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0)';
// cx2.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
// cx2.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in"


cx2.beginPath();
cx2.arc(180, 180, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
cx2.closePath();
cx2.fillStyle = '#6495ED';
cx2.fill();
cx2.lineWidth = 2;
cx2.strokeStyle = '#003300';
cx2.stroke();
```

The issue with clearRect is that it leaves a white rectangle and I want to have it transparent, as the layer below has a background.

Other layers will be stacked on top and all needs to be transparent, the deleting of the circle and redrawing should not affect this.

I have tried a few other commands, but none have worked so far. clearRect gives me this white rectangle:

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/dorien/tghgsw5g/

Comment: If you could share a JSFiddle or something demonstrating this I think it should be easy to debug.

Comment: I've quickly put my code in jsfiddle. Not sure why the image isn't showing, I think it's the same as how I have it. https://jsfiddle.net/dorien/tghgsw5g/

Comment: I tried to make a jsfiddle with the given code, but I have gotten no matching results. clearRect had no issues when used as above.https://jsfiddle.net/vxtrmpk5/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear Canvas Rect (but keep background)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596434/clear-canvas-rect-but-keep-background)

Comment: Perhaps it is because I have set my background as cx1.drawImage(img, 0, 0); of the first context?

Comment: @dorien I don't see any problems with your fiddle. If I uncomment the clearRect line, it works as expected. Zooming out a bit, I don't think you need to create different contexts for the same canvas element. The contexts don't "stack" as you said. You could have multiple canvas _elements_ that were stacked, if you wanted to though.

Comment: I see. So there is no way of keeping the circle on cx1 while erasing cx2.

Comment: The circles are drawn on the same canvas as the image.  The circles pixels overwrite the image in the 2D array of stored pixels, so they aren't recoverable anyways without more extensive changes, such as a separate canvases.  See the duplicate post.  It looks fine on jsfiddle because the image isn't loaded. @JohnSmith the background you set is on a div and not part of the canvas, so it's kept.

Comment: In my full code it is still giving me the white rectangle though (regardless of the layers thing). I wish the img function would work in jfiddle. Any reason for that? Otherwise I could show: https://jsfiddle.net/dorien/tghgsw5g/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one context: `.getContext('2d')` returns the `CanvasRenderingContext2D` for the canvas. It does not create new contexts. So, when you `cx2.clearRect(0,0,300,300);` you're also clearing `cx1` because, well, it's the same context.

If you want separate "layers" you need to create separate `<canvas>`'s and position them on top of each other.